# how to get the next immediate following::node() <w:tbl> elements of the context node using xslt2.0?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0, xpath-2.0

I want to convert one xml format to another xml format by using xslt 2.0.Now i want to get the next immediate following::node()  elements of the context node.for example,

**This is my xml document:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
        <w:document xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main"
                    xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml">
        <w:body>
      <w:p>para1</w:p>   <!-- assume this as context node  -->
      <w:tbl>table data 1</w:tbl>
      <w:tbl>table data 2</w:tbl>
      <w:p>para2</w:p>
      <w:tbl>table data 3</w:tbl>
      <w:tbl>table data 4</w:tbl>
      <w:tbl>table data 5</w:tbl>
      <w:tbl>table data 6</w:tbl>
      <w:p>para3</w:p>
   </w:body>
  </w:document>
```

So,as per the context node mentioned in the above xml file, i want to select only table data 1 and table data2.

for example, if my context node is para2 then i want to select table data 3,table data 4,table data 5 and table data 6 only.

So, i have written xslt like this,

```
<xsl:for-each select="following::node()/self::w:tbl">
     <xsl:choose>
         <xsl:when test="self::w:tbl">
             <xsl:apply-templates select="self::w:tbl"></xsl:apply-templates>
          </xsl:when>                                             
     </xsl:choose>                                         
</xsl:for-each>
```

But it produced wrong result...

Please Guide me to get out of this issue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a function that might be useful:

```
<xsl:function name="f:adjacently-following" as="element()*">
  <xsl:param name="start" as="element()"/>
  <xsl:param name="elementName" as="xs:QName"/>
  <xsl:variable name="next" select="$start/following-sibling::*[1]"/>
  <xsl:if test="node-name($next) = $elementName">
      <xsl:sequence select="$next, f:adjacently-following($next, $elementName)"/>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:function>
```

Then you can call `f:adjacently-following(., xs:QName('w:tbl'))`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you were positioned on a **w:p** element, you could get all the following **w:tbl** siblings whose first most preceding **w:p** was the current element

```
<xsl:apply-templates 
   select="following-sibling::w:tbl
     [generate-id(preceding-sibling::w:p[1]) = generate-id(current())]" />
```

This could be tidied up a little by the use of a **xsl:key**. If you were to define the following key:

```
<xsl:key name="tbl" match="w:tbl" use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::w:p[1])" />
```

Then you could get the following **w:tbl** elements like so:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="key('tbl', generate-id())" />
```

For example, given the following XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
   xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" 
   xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" exclude-result-prefixes="w v">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:key name="tbl" match="w:tbl" use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::w:p[1])" />

   <xsl:template match="w:body">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="w:p[1]" />
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="w:p">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="key('tbl', generate-id())" />
   </xsl:template>   

   <xsl:template match="w:tbl">
      <table><xsl:value-of select="." /></table>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your sample XML, the following is output:

```
<table>table data 1</table>
<table>table data 2</table>
```

Do note this is an XSLT1.0 solution. There might be other ways to do it that only work in XSLT2.0.

Comment: thank you Tim. Could you please tell me if my current context node is <w:tbl>table data 1</w:tbl> then will it work for this situation?

Comment: No, this solution will only work if your current context is a **w:p** element.

Answer (score 1):

This XSLT 2.0 style-sheet...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main"
  xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xsl w v">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
 <root>
   <xsl:for-each-group select="w:document/w:body/(w:p|w:tbl)" group-starting-with="w:p" >
    <p>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()" />
    </p>
   </xsl:for-each-group>
 </root>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="w:tbl">
  <table>
    <xsl:value-of select="." />
  </table>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

...when applied to this input document...

```
<w:document xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml">
    <w:body>
        <w:p>para1</w:p>
        <!-- assume this as context node -->
        <w:tbl>table data 1</w:tbl>
        <w:tbl>table data 2</w:tbl>
        <w:p>para2</w:p>
        <w:tbl>table data 3</w:tbl>
        <w:tbl>table data 4</w:tbl>
        <w:tbl>table data 5</w:tbl>
        <w:tbl>table data 6</w:tbl>
        <w:p>para3</w:p>
    </w:body>
</w:document>
```

...yields...

```
<root>
   <p>para1<table>table data 1</table>
      <table>table data 2</table>
   </p>
   <p>para2<table>table data 3</table>
      <table>table data 4</table>
      <table>table data 5</table>
      <table>table data 6</table>
   </p>
   <p>para3</p>
</root>
```